# how can i make my app compatible with all screen sizes without making different layout files for it?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have a linear layout for buttons so when i run the app on different mobiles some of the buttons get hidden. As my app is ready in terms of code so i want some short technique to make it compatible for all screen sizes.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    tools:context="com.example.android.hiha.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/main_activity_cover">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <include layout="@layout/tool_bar"
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"></include>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/btn_list_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">
    <include
        layout="@layout/button_list"
        android:id="@+id/button_list"></include>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn_list_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <include
        layout="@layout/bottom_section_main"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_section_main"></include>

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**button_list.xml (landscape)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/about_btn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/about"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="4dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/about_txt_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="About"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digital_lib_btn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/digital_library"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/digital_lib_txt_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Digital Library"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/blogs_btn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/blog"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blogs_txt_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Forums/Blogs"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/affltd_organization_btn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/organization"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/affltd_organization_txt_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Organizations"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gallery_btn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/gallery"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gallery_txt_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Gallery"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/feedback_btn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/feedback"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/feedback_txt_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Feedback"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/scientific_proof_btn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/scientific_proof"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scientific_proof_txt_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Scientific Proof"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tender_btn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tender"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tender_txt_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Tenders"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contact_us_btn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/contact"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_us_txt_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Contact Us"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView about_btn;

    ImageView feedbackBtn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
                Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
        about_btn=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.about_btn);
        about_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Create custom dialog object
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                // Include dialog.xml file
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.about_dialog);
                // Set dialog title
                dialog.setTitle("Choose one");
                dialog.show();
                ImageView sarasvati_btn = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.sarasvati_btn);
                sarasvati_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Sarasvati_Activity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                ImageView about_btn_dialog=(ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.about_btn_dialog);
                about_btn_dialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,About_Us_Activity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        feedbackBtn=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.feedback_btn);
        facebook=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.facebook_icon);
        twitter=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.twitter_icon);
        youtube=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.youtube_icon);
        instagram=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.instagram_icon);
 }
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.feedback_btn:
                Intent j=new Intent(this,FeedbackActivity.class);
                startActivity(j);
                break;
            case R.id.contact_us_btn:
                Intent k=new Intent(this,Contact_Us_Activity.class);
                startActivity(k);
                break;
            case R.id.affltd_organization_btn:
                Intent gs = new Intent(this,AffiliatedOrganizationsActivity.class);
                startActivity(gs);
                break;

            case R.id.gallery_btn:
                Intent l=new Intent(this,Gallery.class);
                startActivity(l);
                break;

            case R.id.scientific_proof_btn:
                Intent sc=new Intent(this,Scientific_Evidences_Actiivity.class);
                startActivity(sc);
                break;

            case R.id.blogs_btn:
                Intent blogs=new Intent(this,BlogActivity.class);
                startActivity(blogs);
                break;

            case R.id.tender_btn:
                Intent tender=new Intent(this,WebViewActivity.class);
                tender.putExtra("URL","url");
                startActivity(tender);
                break;
            case R.id.digital_lib_btn:
                Intent lib=new Intent(this,DigitalLibraryActivity.class);
                startActivity(lib);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //Execute your code here
        finish();

    }

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        int orientation;
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
                Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
             orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
            // or = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        }else {
            orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
        }
        // Add code if needed
        setRequestedOrientation(orientation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Percent Relative Layout
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

Constraint Layout
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Use layout_weight.  Research about them. I have started using layout_weight and they adjust to any screen size.  Weights are used in LinearLayouts and TableLayouts.  There may be more but those are the two i have used them in.  If you want space in between items, go to the layout text screen and type

```
<View
```

and press enter. it should guide you from there.  Views also can have weight too.

Answer (score 0):

do not give any fix size to button or TextView
as per above code you give

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/about_btn"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/about"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:elevation="4dp"/>``
```

Imageview you give fix size 50dp for(height and width).Image view Hight&Width never change when you run different mobile phone.
so most of use Wrap_content and Match_Parent

Comment: if i'll not provide the fixed size then the button layout file will get distorted!

Comment: there four resolution screen
1-:hdpi
2-:xhdpi
3-:xxhdpi
4-:xxxhdpi

you create four dimens and drawable folder for four resoulation.
ex hdpi--12dp(in dimen_hdpi)
xhdpi--14dp(in dimen_xhdpi)
xxhdpi--16dp(in dimen_xxhdpi)
xxxhdpi--18dp(in dimen_xxxhdpi)

so when you run app for three difference resoulation than txt view get above dimen automatically